# Project reference elements Morphia

Tags: mongodb, morphia

Does it possible project attributes'reference elements in Morphia?

I have an structure similar to this:

```
@Entity
public class Event {
    @Embedded
    private List<Edition> editions;
}

public class Edition {
  @Reference
  private List<Lecture> lectures
}
```

When I try project some attributes of reference element such like this:

```
final MorphiaIterator<Event, Event> aggregate = this.basicDAO.getDs().
                <Event, Event>createAggregation(Event.class).
                match(query).
                project(
                        Projection.projection("editions.address"),
                        Projection.projection("editions.ageLimit"),
                        Projection.projection("editions.bannerURL"),
                        Projection.projection("editions.description"),
                        Projection.projection("editions.endsIn"),
                        Projection.projection("editions.establishment"),
                        Projection.projection("editions.iconURL"),
                        Projection.projection("editions.id"),
                        Projection.projection("editions.observation"),
                        Projection.projection("editions.startsIn"),
                        Projection.projection("editions.lectures.endsIn"),
                        Projection.projection("editions.lectures.name"),
                        Projection.projection("editions.lectures.startsIn"),
                        Projection.projection("editions.position"),
                        Projection.projection("name")
                ).
                aggregate(Event.class);

    return aggregate.next();
```

I receive the following message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mongodb.BasicDBObject cannot be cast to com.mongodb.DBRef
```

Actually, this is just a doubt base in fact that I could execute another query to retrieve just the attributes that I want an then complete my object

Comment: without code showing your setup, your chances of getting help approach 0.

Comment: Sorry @evanchooly I thought that is an problem where just "yes" or "no" base in mongo characteristics. I guess that I can not do that base in the fact that this is another collection by reference instead a embedded collection